# How can I see/display the value of a variable from views.py?

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
while i<10:
    temp = random.choice(possible)
    token = token + temp
    i=i+1

userf.email_token = token
```

I want to display/see the value of the variable token. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using the test server (`./manage.py runserver`), printing to stdout (`print token`) will print to the console. you can also drop into a debugger, which will also use the console (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`)

Comment: Is there any way to dump that variable instead of print to see the type of the varialbe and other information about that variable?

Comment: `pdb` (preferably `ipdb`) is the way to go for proper debugging

Answer (score 1):

Use pprint module

```
import pprint 
pprint.pprint(token)
```

or raise exception to stop script execution

```
raise Exception(token)
```

to see *type* type `type()` ;)

```
type(token)
```